# Adding images to version control with Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, ide, subclipse

I know that when using Subversion, adding/copying/renaming files must be done via 'svn add' or 'svn copy' etc.  In my Eclipse IDE, I use Subclipse to work with subversion.  It's easy enough to add text-based files to version control (ie. php/html/js files) - but how do I properly add images to version control using Subclipse?

Thanks, Brian

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing? I've added images to repository many times with Subclipse, without any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it turns out that you can't, just use SVN or (if on Windows) Tortoise to add the files outside of Eclipe, directly from the file system.